# How can I set client configuration for MySQL Workbench without an installed server?

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-workbench

Say I have installed MySQL workbench on windows 7 without a server, and I'm connecting to a remote server.
How can I set client configuration (like the [client] section in 'my.ini') for the workbench?
Or maybe I get it the wrong way and the client loads the configuration from the server that it connects to?

**Update:**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The configuration I'm trying to set is command lines to run at the beginning of each transaction, such as:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
```

If MySQL server is installed on my machine, then I can add the following lines to the 'my.ini' file in the installation folder:

```
[client]
init-command="SET autocommit=0; SET tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'"
```

Comment: What exactly are you seeking to configure?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Is it any use to know that one can set both [`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) and [`tx_isolation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation) globally, at the server (and thus not need to set it on every connection)?

Comment: But not always do I have the permissions to set such parameters on the server...

Answer (score 1):

You asked this a long time ago, and so maybe this is no longer relevant to you, but I will include a way of doing this here to benefit others.

In Workbench open your connection properties.
On the Connection Tab, select the Advanced Tab.
In there add the following two options to the Others section (obviously change the readDefaultFile location to the location of your my.ini).

readDefaultFile=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini
readDefaultGroup=client

Now opening connections should read the client section from that my.ini as required.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench doesn't load any server configuration file for its own configuration. It can work on such a config file for a server, however (server section, usually `[mysqld]` only).

MySQL Workbench's configuration is a manual step you have to do in order to connect to a server (be it local or remote).

Comment: I wasn't looking for configuration of how to connect to a server, if that what you meant. I was looking for configuration to set the behavior of a client upon connecting to a server.

Comment: And that client is? If it is MySQL Workbench then the [client] section of the config file is irrelevant (not read by WB). If it is '''not''' MySQL Workbench then your question is not relevant for WB.

Comment: My WB seems to be affected by the [client] section; for instance, when I set the 'tx_isolation' variable it actually affects the isolation level of the WB's transactions. I'm using MySQL WB 5.2.47 and MySQL server 5.6.